# Can't debug this code

Tags: errors

I have been horribly stuck for the last four days with these warnings in my thesis which are not letting the code compile:

```
Errors: 0, Warnings: 3, Bad boxes: 0
sectsty.sty
LaTeX Warning: Command \underbar has changed.
sectsty.sty
LaTeX Warning: Command \underline has changed.
BOONDOX-cal.sty
LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `boondox-cal', but the package provides `BOONDOX-cal'.
```

What's frustrating me is that if I open the last successful backed up code, it compiles and then when I add a few more lines which all look correct to me syntax-wise, it starts spitting these errors and then even if I remove those newly added lines, the errors remain. But when I copy the code to a new tex file, it works! I just don't understand all this at all. Any kind of help will be really appreciated.

I think the error is in the preamble because of the extent I could shorten the rest of the code while still getting the error. Here is a shortened code snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym,amsmath}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{boondox-cal}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{old-arrows}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine} %for isomorphism maps
\newcommand{\isom}{\mathrel{\setstackgap{S}{-0.5pt}\ensurestackMath{\Shortstack{\scriptstyle\sim\\ \longrightarrow}}}}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}
$\upvarepsilon$
\end{document}
```

Comment: These are only warnings not errors. They shouldn't affect the output. The real error is that \upvarepsilon is not defined. You can avoid it by loading the upgreek package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer But for some reason, latex is not generating a pdf on compilation even if they are just warnings. I don't know why that's happening. By the way, I did use the upgreek package in my original code.

Comment: Sorry but how should one help you if you don't show the problematic code but some fantasy code?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry, actually I was not sure if I should do that since it was quite a long code and I read that I should always submit a minimal working example. I can share the whole code if that works.

Comment: @nik610 it is correct that you should create an MWE to aid possible helpers. But you have to make sure that your MWE still shows the problematic behaviour you're facing in your real work.

Comment: @nik610 what it is meant for MWE is that you should take your (long) code and reduce it so that it is *minimal* but still shows the problem. It is my experience that normally whilst doing that you'll find the error...